# How to increase quality of Spacy results?

Tags: python-2.7, information-extraction, spacy

I've installed Spacy and the **en_core_web_sm** data.
If I try my code that should extract person information on random news articles I get roughly 50% correct data. The rest contains issues and mistakes.

```
import spacy
import io

from spacy.en import English
from spacy.parts_of_speech import NOUN
from spacy.parts_of_speech import ADP as PREP

nlp = English()
ents = list(doc.ents)
for entity in ents:
    if entity.label_ == 'PERSON':
        print(entity.label, entity.label_, ' '.join(t.orth_ for t in entity))
```

On this document for instance:
http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-10-30/is-nauru-virtually-a-failed-state/6869648
I receive these results:

```
(377, u'PERSON', u'Lukas Coch)\\nMap')
(377, u'PERSON', u'\\"never')
(377, u'PERSON', u'Julie Bishop')
(377, u'PERSON', u'Tanya Plibersek')
(377, u'PERSON', u'Mr Eames')
(377, u'PERSON', u'DFAT')
(377, u'PERSON', u'2015Andrew Wilkie')
(377, u'PERSON', u'Daniel Th\xfcrer')
(377, u'PERSON', u'Australian Aid')
(377, u'PERSON', u'Nauru')
(377, u'PERSON', u'Rule')
```

How is it possible to increase the quality of the results?

Would the entire **en_core_web_md** help?

Or are those NLP library approaches always worse than deep learning packages like TensorFlow for instance?

Answer (score 4):

POS tagging with spacy or nltk would give you raw data based on the models it uses.
The data will have errors and would need preprocessing or classifying models to filter invalid data.
Few suggestions:

1. Pass it through a comprehensive set of regex rules which will cover most practical person names. e.g. ignore person names like "DARPA" , "CNN", "BAFTA", "2015Andrew"
2. Check if each component of the word exists in a reference dictionary, and lemma of the word is different from the word, that increases the possibility of it not being a person name.
   e.g Mark Tailor, Rob Bolt are valid person names, but Marked Tailored, or Robs Bolt might not be.
3. Use one more Named Entity recognition tool like Stanford NER : http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html and take the best of both outputs by fuzzy matching.
4. User probablistic models to classify name patterns & gibberish. This module uses markov chains to identify gibberish like "jdfgwerqdv" compared to a word like "overflow" or a name like "andrew", based on probability distribution of sequence of characters.
   https://github.com/rrenaud/Gibberish-Detector

Answer (score 2):

In general, POS tagging is only as good at the data that is represents, and in cases where unseen data is tagged, labels might not be as reliable.

SpaCy uses a [Perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) Model for tagging, which is a type of Artificial Neural model. It will most likely perform quite similarly to other TensorFlow models.

It seems that most cases where `PERSON` is used, it is correct (6/11), so to improving the data and retraining is probably the best solution.

Taken from the [SpaCy website on training](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/training), you can retrain the model adding your additional data that is mislabeled.

```
from spacy.vocab import Vocab
from spacy.tagger import Tagger
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
vocab = Vocab(tag_map={'N': {'pos': 'NOUN'}, 'V': {'pos': 'VERB'}})
tagger = Tagger(vocab)
doc = Doc(vocab, words=['I', 'like', 'stuff'])
gold = GoldParse(doc, tags=['N', 'V', 'N'])
tagger.update(doc, gold)
tagger.model.end_training()
```

If you add your own `vocab` it will perform better in cases of unseen words.